# excel formula for TODAY() if other cell is not bank?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: img]

I need a formula if I do not have a date in a cell "C6","C7".... to not have a value of  -42008 in "F6","F7"... to be empty. Formula that I use to see the "Days to:" in Colum "F" is in FX bar (=C2-TODAY())
And also needs me, if someone has an idea if CheckBox is TRUE, for example row 2, to be deleted or changes color.

Comment: Just test if C6 is blank like `IF(C2="","",C2-TODAY())`. For your second question, you can use Conditional Formatting to test whether the underlying cell value is TRUE. I don't like checkboxes in spreadsheets and suggest just changing column G to a choice between "OK" and "Not OK" enforced with Data Validation. If you aren't familiar with Conditional Formatting or Data Validation, it looks like this project would be a good time to learn; there's lots of great info out there.

Comment: @DougGlancy you've answered the question in the comment ...can I copy/paste for the points?!

Comment: @DougGlancy ...damn ...took my eye of the ball again and someone's in before me!

Comment: @DougGlancy ..p.s. do you know of any add-ins that "find links" for excel 2013? (my 2003, or was it 2007, add-in was great but seems to have given up the ghost)

Comment: @DougGlancy thanks for references ... suspect it is BillM's add-in that has stopped working (10 years of use over three versions of Excel isn't bad going for a free tool so I'm not complaining)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for the 1st question, you can use this pattern:

```
= if(Logical_Test;[Value_if_true];[Value_if_false])
```

for example on your table & data :

```
= IF(C2=""؛""؛C2-TODAY())
```

for the 2nd question you can use Conditional Formatting in HOME tab: 
go to **HOME tab**, Next on **Conditional Formatting**, and select  **New Rule...** 
in new window select "**use a formula to determine which cells format**" 
then in "**format values where this formula is true**" box type your condition
also click on **format** button and set your format on fill or border or else .

Hope of Success

Comment: Note that in the US you'll use commas, not semicolons.